# actix_web invalid header provided

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am getting this error running an actix-web based server

```
ERROR actix_http::h1::dispatcher] stream error: Request parse error: Invalid Header provided
```

The handler code is this:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Data {
   some_data: String
};
async fn handler_post(
  request: HttpRequest,
  data: web::Json<Data>
) -> impl Responder {
  HttpResponse::OK()
     .json(ApiResponse {
        status: "success"
     })
}
```

The headers being sent are accept, Content-Type and User-Agent. I don't know how to make it work. By the way, i'm using actix-web 4.

Comment: please add the request and `Cargo.toml` in your question.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, can't figure out the cause

Comment: I actually fixed my issue but forgot to post the answer. It wasn't header related at all. I forgot what I changed. Can you post your code? It might jog my memory.

Comment: I've seen the same error message in AWS logs....it turned out to be completely different issue. In my case, I was servicing a non-existent static dir. fixing my paths etc resurrected my app

Answer (score 1):

I tried the handler with `actix` version `4` and facing no issue

**src/main.rs**

```rs
use actix_web::{get, post, web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder, HttpRequest};
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[get("/")]
async fn hello() -> impl Responder {
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hello world!")
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Data {
   some_data: String
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct ApiResponse<'a> {
   status: &'a str
}

#[post("/")]
async fn handler_post(
  request: HttpRequest,
  data: web::Json<Data>
) -> impl Responder {
  HttpResponse::Ok()
     .json(ApiResponse {
        status: "success"
     })
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .service(hello)
            .service(handler_post)
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "..."
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
actix-web = "4"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
```